# Dynamically refreshing the content based on search text

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am building a react application in which I have media files loaded in a table view. I have a search bar on this page. I have seen many pages dynamically refresh the content as user keep entering text in search bar. How can I do that? I have a search api ready on backend. This api gives me the new content to load on the basis of search text. Currently I can think of making a call to this api whenever search icon is clicked. But I want to make it dynamic such as content should get refreshed automatically when user keeps entering the text. How can I do this?

Comment: input.oninput=refresh;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your event handler for the button already works, you can simply use it for the **`onChange` event** of the search input field:

```
const mySearchHandler = function(event) {
     const searchQuery = event.target.value;

     ...
}

...

<input onChange={mySearchHandler} />
```

---

You may want to be careful not to make API calls too often, e.g. if the user types fast. Lodash's [`_.throttle()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.2#throttle) may be a good starting point.

Comment: Can you please explain how can I use _.throttle() for the case you mentioned.